# Merge Column Into Rows In Html Table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-table, bootstrap-4

Rowspan And Colspan For Building HTML Tables.

I want the first five column in a single row without any data as shown in editable fig. ,Can use rowspan or colspan.

Only The Last Two Column is as it is as shown in the editable fig. And There should be a row before that two column which is the combination of the five columns and that should be blank.

### [image]

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
   <table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
        <th>Date!</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>10/10/2020</td>
        <td>2020</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>4:30pm</td>
        <td>hrishi</td>
        <td>male</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>$100</td>
         <td>10/10/2020</td>
         <td>2020</td>
         <td>January</td>
         <td>4:30pm</td>
         <td>hrishi</td>
         <td>male</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below.

```
   <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5" rowspan="3" width="300"></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hrishi</td>
        <td>male</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>hrishi</td>
         <td>male</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Sorry ...Don't want to use style="width: 100px;". So I edited my code ..pls see it again.

Comment: I've updated the code. I have removed the `thead` and `tbody` tags, to allow the rowspan to be applied. Since your first row is spanning to the bottom of the table, you can not consider it as a header row.

Comment: I want to use bootstrap classes to increase the width. Don't want to use width ="300".

Answer (score 0):

I applied the bootstrap css class in css file and got my answer.

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" rowspan="3" class="w-70"></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hrishi</td>
      <td>male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hrishi</td>
      <td>male</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### And add the width property in style.css file -

```
.w-70 {
 width: 70%;
 }
```